# Remove empty line from my file

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I need to remove empty line from my file. I am using a string builder.

This is how the output is coming

```
1619023|crecxcationCAF|01/01/1901
1619023|flagccxxOLP|faux
1619023|topElcdcssigibleCB|faux

1619022|csSeuidslScodssdsdreFicPPProspect|1000
1619022|csEndesdsdsddttementMax4|60
1619022|csTresoCliPlus6mSeuil3|300
```

Expected output is

```
1619023|creationCAF|01/01/1901
1619023|flagOLP|faux
1619023|topEligibleCB|faux
1619022|csSeuilScoreFicPPProspect|1000
1619022|csEndettementMax4|60
1619022|csTresoCliPlus6mSeuil3|300
```

Comment: Ok, you already have it. Any questions ?

Comment: use `if (!line.isEmpty()){//add it to the StringBuilder}`, then, only open an `FileOutputStream` and write the content to it.

Comment: @redxef - `if (! (line==null || line.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
String str = yourtext.replaceAll("(?m)^\s+$", "");
```

The other way is to check

```
if (readLine.isEmpty() || readLine.trim().equals("\n") || readLine.trim().equals(""))
 continue;
```

Comment: I am not sure about the `"\n"` part. Depending on the OS, we could have CR, LF or CR+LF for newlines

Comment: I would use `System.getProperty("line.seperator")` instead of `"\n"`

Comment: @redxef And I'd prefer ``System.lineSeparator()``

Comment: Good that i know that now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you just read file using `BufferedReader` and read line then when you append line in `StringBuilder` just check line is empty or not like below:

```
StringBuilder fileTextBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String line = ""; //read line here using while loop from BufferedReader 

//when append the string just check following condition
if (line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {
    fileTextBuilder.append(line);
}
```